# Android Fragment Backstack not showing

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, tabs, baseadapter

i'm developing an application where I have tabs and fragments within each tab.  I got it to work where it shows my listview on launch and when I click a name in the list its goes to the next fragment, but when I hit the back button it doesn't go back to the listview I just get a blank screen.  I'm sure it's a simple answer and I have posted some code snippets, if more is needed please let me know.  Thank you for your help.

### FragmentActivity

```
public class HomeStackActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragmentstackctivity);

    // add initial fragment, do not add to back stack, no transition animation
    addFragment(new MyCommentActivity(), false, FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE);
}

void addFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack, int transition) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment1, fragment);
    ft.setTransition(transition);
    if (addToBackStack)
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}


public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (manager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    else
        finish();
}

}
```

### NameClick

```
public class nameOnClickListener implements OnClickListener{
        private int position;
        public nameOnClickListener(int position){
            this.position=position;
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            HashMap<String, String> update = new HashMap<String, String>();
            update = commentList.get(position); 
            Log.d("Testing Click", update.get(MyCommentActivity.KEY_UID));

            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sp.edit();
            edit.putString("profile_id", update.get(MyCommentActivity.KEY_UID));
            edit.putString("profile_type", update.get(MyCommentActivity.KEY_TYPE));
            edit.commit();

            addFragment(new UserProfileActivity(), true, FragmentTransaction.TRANS
```

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
ft.replace(R.id.fragment1, fragment);
```

to:

```
ft.add(R.id.fragment1, fragment);
```

Comment: do not override onBackPressed and try because just by adding to backstack this should work

Comment: Nah that didnt do it still getting a blank screen with the tabs at the bottom.  Ok, I have an activity for the tabs that starts the HomeStackActivity, from there is MyCommentsActivity that uses a baseadapter and when you click the name i need to send the user id and type to the userprofile

Comment: I can share the full project with you